# How do you parse this JSON in Python?

Tags: python, json

JSON below

```
{"result":[
    {
        "spawn_point_id":"89",
        "encounter_id":"1421",
        "expiration_timestamp_ms":"1470105387836",
        "latitude":38.22,
        "longitude": -91.27
    },
    {
        "distance_in_meters":10,
        "encounter_id":"9677"
    },
    {
        "distance_in_meters":10,
        "encounter_id":"1421"
    },
    {
        "spawn_point_id":"11",
        "encounter_id":"2142",
        "expiration_timestamp_ms":"1470105387444",
        "latitude":38.00,
        "longitude": -91.00
    }
]}
```

and i want the output to look like

```
spawn 89 at lat 38.22 long -91.27
spawn 11 at lat 38.00 long -91.00
```

i used `json.loads` and it actually makes the json look funky.

Code so far below:

```
c = json.loads(r.content)
for d in c['result']:
    if d['latitude'] is not None:
        print(str(d['latitude']))
```

seems to kind of work but then get error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "fast0.py", line 11, in <module>
if d['latitude'] is not None:
KeyError: 'latitude'
```

Comment: There is a `json` module in python. It will load a `dict` type object, like a HashMap in Java. Reading the documentation should get you pretty far.

Comment: by funky i mean it adds a u' to prefix of all key & values

Comment: Try `d.get('latitude')` instead of `d['latitude']`.

Comment: Please do not edit a solution into your question. Instead, post it as a separate answer below. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a key that does not exist.  Try:

```
c = json.loads(r.content)
for d in c['result']:
    if 'latitude' in d:
        print(str(d['latitude']))
```